# Html.DisplayFor() não quebrando linha de string

Tags: html, c#, css, string

Nesse código, a ideia é gerar uma lista de registros buscando do banco de dados e mostrando num cshtml as variáveis, para cada item nesse Model.

No Banco, as strings contêm `\n` (line breaks) só que o HTML.DisplayFor não quebra a linha, o texto fica em uma só linha.

Eu resolvi esse problema com a tag `<pre>` mas aí o estilo de fonte fica diferente. 
Tem outro jeito de fazer ele usar os `\n` ? Ou tem outro jeito de estruturar o html para funcionar?

```
<table id="tableRegistro" style="margin:0; width: 100%; border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing:0;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
         <tbody>
             @foreach (var item in Model.Objeto.ObjetoDetalhes.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Tipo.ToUpper() == "RESUMO DA VISITA"))
                {
                   <tr class="row" style="border:0px;margin-left:0;width:50%">
                       <td style="margin-bottom: -3px; margin-top: -3px;font-size:15px">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Registro);
                       </td>
                   </tr>
                }
          </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: tenta adicionar esse estilo `white-space: pre-line` na `<td>`

Comment: descobri e estava respondendo na hora. mas obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inseri o Html.DisplayFor() dentro de um `<p>` (parágrafo) dentro do `<td>`. 
Removi e usei o mesmo id para o parágrafo e escrevi um CSS para o id. 
Assim ele sempre quebra a linha das frases escritas.

```
<td style="margin-bottom: -3px; margin-top: -3px;font-size:15px">
   <p id="tableRegistro">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Registro)</p>                                               
</td>
```

```css
#tableRegistro {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Para mais informações: [MDN Web Doc: white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)